# How to know how much time spent on compile a class or method in hotspot?

Tags: jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

1, I want to know how much time spent on compile a class or method in hotspot during JIT  (We got some timeout issue and we suspect it maybe caused by a long compilation time)? Is there any trace flag or other ways to trace this time?

2,BTW, if the method run on first time , then the compilation time would is 0 as there is totally no compilation process, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JVM flags: `-XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompilation2`

```
    289  425       4       java.time.LocalDate::until (116 bytes)
    292  360       3       java.time.ZoneId::of (85 bytes)   made not entrant
    293  426       4       java.time.LocalDate::from (68 bytes)
    293  386       3       java.time.LocalDate::from (68 bytes)   made not entrant
    293  426   size: 248(96) time: 0 inlined: 54 bytes
    297  425   size: 3688(2272) time: 8 inlined: 1092 bytes
     ^    ^          ^                ^          ^
     |    |          |                |          |
     |    |          compiled bytes   |          bytecodes inlined
     |    compilation ID              method compilation time (ms)
     timestamp (ms from JVM start)
```

Note that

- JIT compiler works in background while the application is running; it is unlikely to cause delays or timeouts.
- There are typically multiple compiler threads; `PrintCompilation` output may appear interleaved.
- A method may be (re)compiled multiple times with a different level of optimization.

Comment: We got the issue that just after deploying\starting application, we got many timeout error in clients when there are a large client requests concurrently , so we suppose that issue maybe caused by long time class load or method compilation, I have no idea if this troubleshooting direction is right, can you kindly give some suggestion?

Comment: BTW, when the method under compiling , if the request to that method would be blocked?  or it still doing the interpret execution, and switch to compiled version when the compilation finished?

Comment: @Jason Compilation does not block a method from execution. It is done in background while a method is interpreted.

Comment: @Jason Use profilers to find the cause of performance problems.

Comment: Andrei, may I know if the github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler support profiling the blocking issue?  Or it just profile CPU time? For example how percentage of the time of a method spent on waiting for IO operation completion. We know some performance issue caused by the high CPU, however other of them caused by the lock or IO blocking.

Comment: @Jason Not yet. Only CPU and heap profiling so far.

Answer (score 0):

[jitwatch](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/jitwatch) can record and display jit compilation logs.

[image: jitwatch screenshot with log]

Comment: Thank you for provide the information, however we  need to do the troubleshooting in Prod environment, I have no idea if jitwatch would have big performance affects.